# кнопка удаления строки из базы данных в laravel

Tags: laravel, button, delete

вот сама кнопка

```html
  <td>
                <form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                    <button type="submit" id="delete-task-{{ $task->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
```

Вот функция в контроллере

```
public function destroy(Task $task)
{

    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Вот роут

```
Route::delete('/', 'PostController@destroy',function (){} );
```

если можно с подробным объяснением , я новичок в данном деле.

Comment: Ну да, это кнопка удаления с функционалом удаления. Что конкретно Вы хотите?

Comment: она не работает, я думал проблема в коде, кнопка должна удалять строку из бд

Comment: а что происходит? Что работает? Ошибки? До метода destroy вообще доходит? Вы пробовали вообще делать dd()?

Comment: кнопка грубо говоря просто обновляет страницу ошибок не вылетает , а по поводу dd я к сожалению не знаю что это такое сейчас отправлюсь также на просторы интернета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Экшн у формы прописан не правильно:**
Нужно указывать ссылку на роут удаление с параметром id удаляемого task, а у Вас сейчас просто ссылка на главную страницу. Экшн контроллера не принимает никакого параметра.

```
action={{ route('task.delete', [$task]) }}
```

**2. Роутер прописан не правильно:**
В url нужно добавить параметры, чтобы обработчик знал какой конкретно task ему удалять.
Вторым параметром нужно передавать ИЛИ экшн контроллера, ИЛИ колбэк функцию, а у Вас и то и другое :)
Плюс удобнее задавать роутам названия, чтобы можно было их использовать для генерации ссылки.

```
Route::delete('/{task}', 'PostController@destroy')->name('task.delete');
```

Почитайте подробнее про [роутинг в оф.документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing).